# Selenium search bar protected ? " undefined local element or method"

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using selenium trying to send a key to a search bar.

This is the code of the search bar.

```
<input type="text" value="XXXXXXX" onblur="ga('send', 'event', 
'Search', 'Champ_de_recherche');" name="champs" id="input_search" aria-
label="Recherche XXX.com" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off">
```

I am unable to locate it with selenium using name / css / class or id selector

```
element = element.find_element(:id, "input_search")
element = element.find_element(:name, "champs")
```

both are returning *"undefined local variable or method `element' for main:Object (NameError)"*

any guess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks like an issue with your code, e.g.:

```
element = element.find_element
```

More specifically this bit:

```
element.find_element
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
browser.find_element
```

or

```
driver.find_element
```

(or similar) ?

Comment: This is totally the answer... When I posted i found the solution... Thank you so much anyway !

Comment: Can you accept the answer so people don't think it's still unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that you don't have `element` defined before attempting to call those methods. If you aren't trying to find a child element from an element, use the `find_element` method off of your `driver` instance